# javascript regexp "subword" replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, cpu-word, substring

I have a phrase like

"everything is changing around me, wonderfull thing+, tthingxx"

and I want to modify every word that contains ***thing at the end of that word, or at most another character after "thing", like "+" or "h" or "x"...

something like

```
string = 'everything is changing around me, wonderful thing+, tthingxx'
regex = new RegExp('thing(\\+|[g-z])$','g');
string = string.replace(regex, '<b>thing$1</b>');
```

what I want? every**thing** is changing around me, wonderful **thing+**, tthingxx

The result of my regexp? anything working... if I remove the $ all the words containing "thing" and at least another character after it are matched:

everything is changing around me, wonderful **thing+**, t**thingx**x

I tryed everything but - in first place I can't understand very well technical english - and second I did't find the answer around.

what I have to do??? thanks in advance

---

the solution I found was using this regular expression

```
/thing([+g-z]){0,1}\b/g
```

or with the RegExp (I need it because I have to pass a variable):

```
myvar = 'thing';
regex = new RegExp(myvar + "([+g-z]){0,1}\\b" , "g");
```

I was missing the escape \ when doing the regular expression in the second mode. But this isn't enough: the + goes out of the **<** b **>** and I don't really know why!!!

---

**the solution that works as I want is the one by @Qtax:**

```
/thing([+g-z])?(?!\w)/g
```

**thank to the community!**

Comment: What you want to obtain isn't clear, at least for me. What's the desired result ?

Comment: I noted that  using `thing(\\+|[g-z]){0,1}` is a bit better, but I don't know how to say to regexp that there is the end of the word. $ doesn't work, \b doesn't work...

Comment: I solved: I tried to use \b istead of **\\b** during the RegExp definition string... now it's ok: `RegExp('thing(\\+|[g-z]){0,1}\\b')`

Comment: @NereoCostacurta: One of many reasons not to use strings to create regular expressions unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @NereoCostacurta, note that your solution won't work with for example `thing+`, only `thing` would match, without the `+`. Added an answer which solves that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue with `+` not matching when using `\b` you could use `(?!\w)` instead of `\b` there, like:

```
thing[+g-z]?(?!\w)
```

Comment: it's perfect, to complete your answer I add `/thing([+g-z])?(?!\w)/g` that remember the first parenthesis like I want, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use boundary in your regex

```
\b\w+thing(\+|[g-z])?\b
```

Comment: the regexp you used replace the whole word, and doesn't work for me with words that ends with +, g, h, i..., z.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, then:

```
string = 'everything is changing around me, wonderful thing+, tthingxx';
string = string.replace(/thing(\b|[+g-z]$)/g, '<b>thing$1</b>');
```

...which results in:

```
every<b>thing</b> is changing around me, wonderful <b>thing</b>+, tthingxx
```

`\b` is a word boundary, so what the regular expression says is anywhere it finds "thing" followed by a word boundary *or* `+` or `g-z` at the end of the string, do the replacement.